# How to access audio waveform buffer when recording using WASAPI in c++?

Tags: c++, audio, wasapi, winmm

I've used winmm library to access the waveform information before with syntax like this `waveInAddBuffer(hwi, &wh[i], sizeof(WAVEHDR));` So I've to pass the pointer that point to the memory block (&wh[i]) where I want to store the waveform data, In order to access it I just have do this wh[i].lpData
Are there a similar function like this in WASAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's [`IAudioCaptureClient::GetBuffer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/audioclient/nf-audioclient-iaudiocaptureclient-getbuffer) method:

> Retrieves a pointer to the next available packet of data in the capture endpoint buffer.
>
> […]
>
> BYTE   **ppData
>
> Pointer to a pointer variable into which the method writes the starting address of the next data packet that is available for the client to read.

See also:

> For a code example that calls the GetBuffer method, see [Capturing a Stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/1d9072dc-4f9b-4111-a747-5eb33ad3ae5b).